# RegEx for filtering java HashMap keys

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to filter as HashMap of String/Int by they key, matching on a RegEx

```
Map<String, Integer> files = new HashMap<>();
files.put("TEST_SALES1212312.zip", 1212312);
files.put("TEST_SALES9846545.zip", 9846545);
files.put("TEST_INVENTORY2153516.zip", 2153516);
files.put("TEST_INVENTORY3651321.zip", 3651321);

String regex = "(TEST_SALES|.)+(.zip)";

List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> matches = files.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getKey().matches(regex))
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

matches.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getKey()));
```

I tested on [RegEx Tester](https://www.regextester.com) and it correctly filtered the inventory items out. However, the above code does not filter any items.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The regex looks wrong.

Comment: _it correctlyed filtered the inventory items out_ Please show us evidence.

Comment: try `"(TEST_SALES.*)(\\.zip)"` ... the regex is clearly wrong, despite what you said

Comment: Thanks @PatrickParker - I just said that it works on the above site (and it does). Your RegEx was correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/QTuIn0/1) might help you to solve your problem. It creates a target group <kbd>()</kbd> for numeric values of your zip files, which you can simply get using <kbd>$1</kbd>:

```
TEST_[A-Z]+([0-9]+).zip
```

[image]

You can escape language specific metachars using <kbd>\</kbd>, if necessary, such as <kbd>.</kbd>.

If your inputs are only limited to your exampled codes, you may reduce the regex boundaries, if you wish, such as [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/W1emC3/1), and it might still match:

```
[A-Z_]+([0-9]+).zip
```

[image]